# How to specify range padding that takes into consideration the maximum value of the functions being plotted?

Tags: bokeh

How to specify range padding that takes into consideration the maximum value of the functions being plotted?

Follows some pictures.

### 1st usecase

with `p.y_range.range_padding = 0.0`, the December plots get clipped.
[image]

### 2nd usecase

with `p.y_range.range_padding = 0.2`, the December plots do not get clipped but there's too much padding on the bottom.
[image]

### 3rd usecase

by manually moving the picture I get what I want:
[image]

I am trying to achieve the 3rd usecase programmatically, i.e no padding on the bottom, but some padding on the top so that the functions for December do not get clipped.
Any tips?

Thanks in advance.

---

### ** Edit

Not exacly the same code that generated the plots above, but [here](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/ridgeplot.html)'s some code that depicts the issue.

```
from numpy import linspace
from scipy.stats.kde import gaussian_kde

from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, FixedTicker, PrintfTickFormatter
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.sampledata.perceptions import probly

import colorcet as cc

output_file("ridgeplot.html")

def ridge(category, data, scale=20):
    return list(zip([category]*len(data), scale*data))

cats = list(reversed(probly.keys()))

palette = [cc.rainbow[i*15] for i in range(17)]

x = linspace(-20,110, 500)

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x))

p = figure(y_range=cats, plot_width=700, x_range=(-5, 105), toolbar_location=None)

for i, cat in enumerate(reversed(cats)):
    pdf = gaussian_kde(probly[cat])
    y = ridge(cat, pdf(x))
    source.add(y, cat)
    p.patch('x', cat, color=palette[i], alpha=0.6, line_color="black", source=source)

p.outline_line_color = None
p.background_fill_color = "#efefef"

p.xaxis.ticker = FixedTicker(ticks=list(range(0, 101, 10)))
p.xaxis.formatter = PrintfTickFormatter(format="%d%%")

p.ygrid.grid_line_color = None
p.xgrid.grid_line_color = "#dddddd"
p.xgrid.ticker = p.xaxis[0].ticker

p.axis.minor_tick_line_color = None
p.axis.major_tick_line_color = None
p.axis.axis_line_color = None

p.y_range.range_padding = 0.12

show(p)
```

The y axis range defaults to a `FactorRange` when passing a list of categories, so an exception is thrown when trying to set the `start` attribute, for instance: `p.y_range.start = 0.5`. How to workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Bokeh 1.3.4, I don't actually think there is any way to accomplish this specific arrangement with categorical factors, except by creating a custom extension of some sort. It certainly seems like a reasonable ask, so I'd encourage you to submit a [feature request on GitHub](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues) with all this information.

At present, the only workaround I can imagine is to not use categorical factors at all. Instead use numeric coordinates for everything, and then use `major_label_overrides` and fixed ticker locations to create a plot that looks like the one you have now, except by using numerical range. You can see an example of tick label overrides [here](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/plotting/file/hatch_grid_band.py).

Comment: An exception is thrown since the y_range is being set with a list of categories (FactorRange). Please see the update to the question with code from bokeh documentation.

Comment: The exception: `RuntimeError: FactorRange.start is a readonly property`.
Thank you for your attention.

Comment: So it is, I had forgotten. I have updated the answer.